# COLUMNS_UPDATED() skips a bit starting with columns in the middle of the table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm using COLUMNS_UPDATED() in a trigger to identify those columns whose values should be written to an audit table. The trigger / auditing had been working fine for multiple years. I noticed yesterday that the auditing is no longer working consistently.

I've listed the first forty columns of the table in question at the bottom for reference, along with the ORDINAL_POSITION from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS. The table has a total of 109 columns.

I added `print COLUMNS_UPDATED()` to my trigger to get some debug info.

When I update `CurrentOnFleaTick`, the 9th column, I see this printed:

`0x0001000000000000000000000000`

This is expected - the 9th column should be represented as the least significant bit of the second byte. Similarly, if I update `HasAttackedAnotherAnimalExplanation` I see this:

`0x0000010000000000000000000000`

Again, expected - the 17th column should be represented as the least significant bit of the third byte.

But... when I update `HouseholdIncludesCats`, I see this:

`0x0000000200000000000000000000`

Not expected! Where you see the `2` there should be a `1`, as `HouseholdIncludesCats` ordinal position is 25, making it the first column represented in the fourth byte, which should be represented in the least significant bit of that byte.

I narrowed things down by updating every column between `HasAttackedAnotherAnimalExplanation` and `HouseholdIncludesCats` and found that the 'off by one' problem I'm having starts with `HouseTrainedId`, ordinal position 24. When updating `HouseTrainedId` I'm expecting

`0x0000800000000000000000000000`

but instead I get

`0x0000000100000000000000000000`

which I believe is wrong, and it is what I expect to be getting for updates to the `HouseholdIncludesCats` column.

I don not believe the mask should skip ahead. The mask is currently not using the most significant bit of the 3rd byte.

I did recently drop a column, but I don't have a record of its ordinal position. Based on the original code that would have created the table, I believe the ordinal position of the column that was dropped was NOT 24. (I think it was 7... It had been defined after the `BreedIds`.)

I'm not necessarily looking for a deep root cause determination. If there was something I could do to reset whatever internal data SQL Server uses that'd be fine. Sort of like a rebuild index idea for table metadata? Is there something like that that might fix this?

Thanks in advance for helpful answers! :)

```
COLUMN_NAME ORDINAL_POSITION
PetId   1
AdopterUserId   2
AdoptionDeadline    3
AgeMonths   4
AgeYears    5
BreedIds    6
Color   7
CreatedOn   8
CurrentOnFleaTick   9
CurrentOnHeartworm  10
CurrentOnVaccinations   11
FoodTypeId  12
GenderId    13
GuardianForMonths   14
GuardianForYears    15
HairCoatLength  16
HasAttackedAnotherAnimalExplanation 17
HasAttackedAnotherAnimalId  18
HasBeenReferredByShelter    19
HasHadTraining  20
HasMedicalConditions    21
HasRecentlyBittenExplanation    22
HasRecentlyBittenId 23
HouseTrainedId  24
HouseholdIncludesCats   25
HouseholdIncludesChildren5to10  26
HouseholdIncludesChildrenUnder5 27
HouseholdIncludesDogs   28
HouseholdIncludesOlderChildren  29
HouseholdIncludesOtherPets  30
HouseholdOtherPets  31
KnowsCommandDown    32
KnowsCommandPaw 33
KnowsCommandSit 34
KnowsCommandStay    35
KnowsOtherCommands  36
LastUpdatedOn   37
LastVisitedVetOn    38
ListingCodeId   39
LitterTypeClumping  40
```

Comment: Including the DDL of your table would be far better than a list of the columns and the ordinal position.

Comment: How about the table definition and the trigger code?

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql#remarks) *explicitly* state "The `ORDINAL_POSITION` column of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` view is not compatible with the bit pattern of columns returned by `COLUMNS_UPDATED`", and helpfully include a query that is. (My unverified(!) guess would be that using the `column_id` from `sys.columns` also works, once again proving that the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views really should not be used in preference to the native metadata views.)

Answer (score 1):

So... I thought I had googled enough before posting this, but I guess I hadn't. I found this:

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/columns_updated-and-phantom-fields

using `COLUMNPROPERTY()` to get `ColumnID` is definitely the way to go.